# How to send double[][] array data using Apache Thrift from/to Java and C++

Tags: java, rpc, thrift

I am working on an HPC project. My design consists of Java and C++ masters and workers. My basic experiment is to produce a matrix of 9000x9000 double elements, say double[9000][9000], at master side written in java, and then send it to some clients written in C++, do calculations and send back to master. I know Thrift supports lists, sets, and containers beside primitive types. I could do these steps:

1. convert the matrix into a list at master
2. serialize it using Thrift
3. send it to worker
4. deserialize list and convert into matrix
5. do computation and again convert the result into list
6. serialize list and send back to java master
7. desrialize list and convert into matrix.

I think this is a long journey. Is there a better way so accomplish this task?
How about representing the matrix as binary? If the binary representation is the best option, how can I effectively convert from double[][] to binary ad vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Thrift allows for nested containers, so something like this should do:

```
typedef list< list< double>>  Matrix

service Nebukadnezar {
   void EnterTheMatrix( 1: Matrix matrix);
}
```

If called with `thrift -gen java yourfile.thrift` This gives you

```
public interface Iface {
    public void EnterTheMatrix(List<List<Double>> matrix) 
      throws org.apache.thrift.TException;
}
```

The big question is, however, whether this is a good idea or not. You will have to test whether that serves your needs w/regard to time and/or memory used to convert data.

If the matrix is **sparse**, I'd recommend to send only the used data, like this:

```
struct MatrixCell {
  1: i16 x
  2: i16 y
  3: double data
}

typedef list< MatrixCell>  SparseMatrix
```

Comment: This is actually a solution that I proposed in the question. The matrix is not sparse. I could use [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) for serialization. It is very fast and can easily turn almost anything into byte array. Unfortunately, it is only for java. If there is some efficient serialization that works for both java and c++, I could use it for serialization and use Thrift for cross-language communication.

Comment: (1) Just give it a shot and see whether or not it is fast etc. enough. If it does work as planned, no need to invest more valuable time. (2) If it doesn't - well, you can always build your own binary format, handcrafting a serializer for both ends, if that is necessary. IEEE floats are standardized, so not much of a problem. Beware of different byte orders. All else is easy. Then send it as `binary` element. If it is not a public API you can do whatever you want.